# Display a table of text in power bi

Tags: html-table, powerbi

I need to display the below table as it is in power bi. The text is going to be the same and it is not from a data source.  I dont want to paste this as image as I want this to be editable in power bi desktop itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click Enter Data from the ribbon and enter your text into the two columns. Then display inside a table visual.